# Visual Basic form .close() method

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have the below snippet of code:

```
'Handle level specific properties
Select Case ScoreCard.CurrentDifficulty
    Case 1
        intImageCount = 2 'This is the number of images to show at any given time on screen +1

        'debug
        ScoreCard.CurrentDifficulty = 6
    Case 2
        intImageCount = 3 'This is the number of images to show at any given time on screen +1
    Case 3
        intImageCount = 5 'This is the number of images to show at any given time on screen +1
    Case 4
        intImageCount = 2  'This is the number of images to show at any given time on screen +1
    Case 5
        intImageCount = 5 'This is the number of images to show at any given time on screen +1
    Case 6
        frmLevel3_HouseOfMirrors.Show()
        Me.Close()
        Return
End Select
```

When `case 6` is executed `frm3_HouseOfMirrors.Show()` executes and my new form opens. `Me.close` executes as well but my problem is that the script then gets to the return line. Isn't `me.Close()` suppose to stop all execution of code on the current form and unload its self from memory?

Answer (score 2):

Just call `frmLvl3_HouseOfMirrors.ShowDialog()` instead of `.Show()`, this will stop the execution of code until the new form is closed.

Or if you want to cancel the execution of the rest of code try the [Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instruction. You have to detect you want to finish and add it outside this `Sub`, because `.Close()` didnt stop the execution of code.

Comment: @DeAn Hmm? You remove the answer as correct. Didnt worked for you? Need anything else?

Comment: Hi, Just seeing this now.This partially works. Problem is that after execution of the opened dialog window it returns to the main window and continues to execute the code instead of completely closing the previous form. It seems to just pause execution which is not ideal for my situation. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @DeAn Have you tried with the `Exit` instruction? You can exit the function, or the loop, or the application. Put it after the `Me.Close`: For example `Exit Sub`

Comment: `Exit Sub` followed by `Return` is redundant, they have the same function.

Answer (score 1):

No, the "close" method just closes the form, but the program execution will continue. If you want to stop code execution until a form is closed, you could make it modal.

In VBA it would look like this:
frmLevel3_HouseOfMirrors.Show vbModal

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't `me.Close()` suppose to stop all execution of code on the current form and unload its self from memory?

No. [`Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx) does exactly what it says: it closes the visual, interactive representation of the form.<sup>1</sup> It doesn’t affect code execution directly. It *does* make sure that `Form_Closing` and then `Form_Closed` are called, however. But the rest of the code execution is unaffected; in particular, the current method runs through normally. After that, other methods on the form may or may not be called as necessary (and, as mentioned, `Closing` and `Closed` *will* be called).

---

<sup>1</sup> And, yes, it releases the form’s resources unless the form was shown via `ShowDialog` rather than plain `Show`.